# Weighted Set Cover Problem Minimizing Average Weight

Tags: set-cover

In the traditional weighted set cover problem, we aim at minimizing the sum of the weight of the selected sets. Is there any problem/literature that aim at minimizing the average weight of the selected sets (i.e., sum of the weight / number of sets selected)?